# Selenium WD NullPointerException while executing simple JS code

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Spent 1 day on finding the solution to the following problem:

Can't execute even simple js code using selenium WD. It always returns NullPointerException. Already read tonns of answers but still can't find the reason. The code below is the code after 1 day investigation (I just have tried everything):

```
WebDriver driver2;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver2;
driver.get(baseUrl+ "/");
js.executeScript("return showAlert()");
```

Here is the original code that is not working as well:

```
    public class DPT_class {
      private WebDriver driver;

      @Before
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

      @Test
      //some testing code here
      driver.get(baseUrl+ "/");
      js.executeScript("return showAlert()");
}
```

the same thing for any other js code such as alert(document.title) with and without return and quotes.
*baseUrl is predefined of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever initialized `driver2` instance?

Comment: Agree with @Smit on this one: the example code given does not assign a value to `driver2`, in which case `js` will not have a value either. Your compiler should be complaining that you are using a value which isn't "definitely assigned".

Comment: I edited the original post. Unfortunately this thing doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Smit says, and per your `NullPointerException`

You've never actually initialized your `WebDriver` object, and you're attemting to cast a null object, to JavaScriptExecutor.

Depending on what sort of browser you want to use, you are able to do..

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // etc...
```

Also, why are you attempting to use 2 driver objects? You should only have 1.  Keep your object named `driver`.

Comment: I edited the original post. Unfortunately this thing doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Have changed

```
private WebDriver driver;
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

to

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

Have no idea why but it works now! Thanks a lot!